# New-ADUser -Manager from different domain

Tags: powershell, user-accounts, active-directory

My Powershell script to create new users does not work when the "Manager" is located in a different domain.

For example, I am creating a user in the domain `contoso.com`, but the manager is located in `foo.contoso.com`:

```
$ New-ADUser -Server "dc.contoso.com:3268" -Manager "CN=Bar,OU=Users,DC=foo,DC=contoso,DC=com" [...]
New-ADUser : The server is unwilling to process the request
```

I have triple checked that the DN is correct. If I pick a user from `contoso.com` and use its DN for the `-Manager` parameter, everything works as expected, so the rest of the supplied parameters are not the issue.

Also, after creating the user with a 'local' manager, I am able to set the correct one from `foo.contoso.com` through the "AD Users and Groups" GUI.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that domain in the same forest? If a DC gets a request talking about a different forest you will get that error. Try and use the full FQDN of a DC in `-Server DC123.contoso.com:3268`. Does your account have access to update the manager's `directReports` attribute?

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Yes, the domain is in the same forest. I actually am using a FQDN of a DC, I omitted this in the question (will edit). Yes, my account has access to that attribute - I assume I couldn't set the manager through GUI otherwise.

Comment: What about the opposite - try using the forest name for `-Server`, like from `(Get-ADForest).Name`. Double-check the DC can find the manager user with `Get-ADUser 'manager' -server contoso.com`. Does it work if you do `Set-ADUser -Manager [...]` instead (after you've created it with a local/blank manager)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe this myself, but I found the solution in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#example-7-set-a-property-for-a-user)!

```
$manager = Get-AdUser -Server "dc.contoso.com:3268" "CN=Bar,OU=Users,DC=foo,DC=contoso,DC=com"
Set-ADUser -Identity NewUser -Manager $manager
```

I have no idea why passing the manager as an object instead of a DN makes a difference, but it works.